# How to select record in msql which starts with a name and followed with digits

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a requirement to retrieve the records like "Name19","Name21","Name56", these kind of records in Mysql.Please help how to get it.

Comment: Does it help you, m8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE YourColumn regexp '^Name[0-9]+'
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
  SELECT * FROM <NameTable> WHERE <Name> LIKE '%[0-9]'
```

Comment: It doesn't matter for you, that in answer need `Name19`, and not `emaN42`?

Comment: @FSou1 its should be some name followed by digits, it matters i need only records of type Name but not emaN.Thankyou all for the reply